# How to add data to a combo with javaScript and then pick with POST?

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

I expose my case, I pick through mysql data and fill a combo with php and smarty, then I have a button to add more data to this combo and bbdd. Everything works correctly but me when POST data collecting that data added to the combo did not pick it up

CODE:

HTML code with smarty which fill the combo, and the button to add the new data to the combo

```
<form action="algo.php" method="post">
<div class="form-field">
<label for="cliente_sector">Sector*</label>
    <select name="cliente_sector" id="cliente_sector">
           {section name=sector loop=$sectores}
                   <option value="{$sectores[sector].sector}">{$sectores[sector].sector}</option>
           {/section}
     </select>
    <p>Sector del cliente</p>
    <label onclick="javascript:anadir('divAnadir')">Nuevo sector</label>
</div>

<div id="divAnadir" style="display: none;">
    Nuevo sector:<input type="text" id="nuevo_sector" name="nuevo_sector" value=""/>
     <input onclick="javascript:nuevoSector()" type="button" value="Añadir nuevo sector "/>
</div>
</form>
```

javascript functions

```
function anadir(a){
if(document.getElementById(a).style.display=="none")
    $("#divAnadir").css("display", "block");
else
    $("#divAnadir").css("display", "none");
}
function nuevoSector(){
var datos = document.getElementById("nuevo_sector").value;
$.get("/ajax/altaNuevoSector.php?sector="+datos, datos, function(data){
    if(data != 1) {
        alert('Nuevo sector añadido');
        $("#divAnadir").css("display", "none");
        $("#cliente_sector").append('<option value=" " selected="selected">'+data+'</option>')
        return true;
    }else{
        alert('Este sector ya existe, pruebe de nuevo.');
        return false;
    }  
});
}
```

Php script to update bbdd and response to javascript:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('../includes/config.php');
if($_GET['sector']){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO clientes_sectores(sector) VALUES ('".$_GET['sector']."')";
    $consulta = $con->ejecutar($sql);

    if(!is_numeric($consulta))
        echo '1';
    else
        echo $_GET['sector'];
}

?>
```

All work fine the data is added to the bbdd and displays in the combo, the problem is that the combo is in a form, by post I try to pick the data, if value cliente_sector is the new one not let me pick it up, the $ _POST ['cliente_sector'] is emptied. How do I fix it?
When i do submit in my form the $_POST['clientes_sector'] if in the combo is selected the new value.

thanks

Comment: I didn't see any POST query in your code can you explain ?

Comment: I have not written. I wrote that the combo is inside a form, the code of form
    <form action="algo.php" method="post">
Then in algo.php the issue $_POST['cliente_sector'] is empty. Thanks

Comment: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)**

Comment: I know it, but isn't a problem because is for admin.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I refresh the page with a js function. Thanks for all.